# php-fpm SIGSEGV redis

Tags: php, redis, segmentation-fault

our website get 502, from the fpm error log, find something like

```
[pool www] child 9489 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV - core dumped) after 426.857147 seconds from start
```

use gdb analyse core file

```
(gdb) bt
 #0  _zend_mm_free_int (heap=0x2bd32f0, p=0x7f61175b4058) at /apps/rpmbuild/php-fpm/srcbuild/php-5.6.12/Zend/zend_alloc.c:2104
 #1  0x00007f611045a481 in generic_multiple_args_cmd (ht=<value optimized out>, return_value=<value optimized out>, 
return_value_ptr=<value optimized out>, this_ptr=<value optimized out>, return_value_used=<value optimized out>, 
keyword=0x7f61104740b1 "RPUSH", keyword_len=5, min_argc=2, out_sock=0x7fff5545f868, has_timeout=0, all_keys=0, can_serialize=1)
at /root/rpmbuild/php-fpm/redis-2.2.5/redis.c:2719
 #2  0x00007f611045bd59 in zim_Redis_rPush (ht=2, return_value=0x33cf440, return_value_ptr=0x7f61176bc5a8, this_ptr=0x33cfc68, 
return_value_used=1) at /root/rpmbuild/php-fpm/redis-2.2.5/redis.c:1965
 #3  0x0000000000870762 in zend_do_fcall_common_helper_SPEC (execute_data=<value optimized out>)
at /apps/rpmbuild/php-fpm/srcbuild/php-5.6.12/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:558
 #4  0x000000000085fff0 in execute_ex (execute_data=0x7f61176bc900) at /apps/rpmbuild/php-fpm/srcbuild/php-5.6.12/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:363
 #5  0x00000000007e3ed2 in zend_call_function (fci=0x7fff5545fb30, fci_cache=<value optimized out>)
at /apps/rpmbuild/php-fpm/srcbuild/php-5.6.12/Zend/zend_execute_API.c:829
 #6  0x00007f61108fea06 in zephir_call_user_func_array_noex () from /apps/srv/php-fpm/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/phalcon.so
 #7  0x00007f61108feae9 in zephir_call_user_func_array_noex () from /apps/srv/php-fpm/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/phalcon.so
 #8  0x00000000035ac890 in ?? ()
 #9  0x00000000031cc448 in ?? ()
 #10 0x00000000032df340 in ?? ()
 #11 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

anyone who knows what happened, how can I solve this problem?

1. List item

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade of `php-redis` solved this problem.